# Issue on Android Video View its not working

Tags: android, android-videoview

I'm playing YouTube from URL, but when I play the video it shows the following error:

> unable to open video

I'm using this code:

```
video =new VideoView(this);
video.setVideoURI(path);

System.out.println("my path"+path);

ctlr = new MediaController(this);
ctlr.setMediaPlayer(video);
video.setMediaController(ctlr);
video.requestFocus();`
```

The path is correct. I checked on the Web also. Why am I getting an error like that?

The links are like: http://www.youtube.com/v/8B-Vu94Sd4M?f=videos&app=youtube_gdata

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't simply give the `VideoView` a Youtube URL and expect it to play the video. This seams to be impossible at all (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162088/video-view-not-playing-youtube-video)).

However, you might want to use a YouTube Intent and let the System handle it: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1007695/streaming-youtube-videos)

Comment: I wanna customize my screen so that it plays youtube video file and some widgets around. Is this possible?

Comment: As I see it from the linked threads above, it doesn't seam so. If it is, the [YouTube API Documentation](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/overview.html) might be the right place to look for it.