# How to play YouTube video in Android native player?

Tags: android, youtube, android-video-player

How to play YouTube video in Android native player? If any one achieved this please let me know the way.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550797/playing-youtube-video-in-android-app

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001590/youtube-video-in-android-native-player

Answer (score 0):

http://apiblog.youtube.com/2012/12/no-webview-required-with-native-youtube.html

maybe this link will be of some assistance ? There are various API's out there that can achieve this for you.

API, an abbreviation of application program interface, is a set of routines, protocols, and tools for building software applications. A good API makes it easier to develop a program by providing all the building blocks. A programmer then puts the blocks together. This API in particular should offer you the best assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can check out the API here:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/

Then you need to register your application (get an API key)
https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/register

And then you can simply add the required methods to your Activity:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/YouTubePlayerView

There is also the createPlayVideoIntentWithOptions, it opens up the native youtube application installed on the device

```
public static Intent createPlayVideoIntentWithOptions (Context context, String videoId, boolean fullscreen, boolean finishOnEnd)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tryout the link below; 
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-android-app/

It's a step by step tutorial.