# Xamarin forms embed youtube video for cross platform

Tags: android, ios, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

Is there a cross-platform solution for `Xamarin` Forms for `Webview` to implement a `youtube video to an activity`. 
(Inb4 Adam Fisher spams his $50 nuget package solution, I'm not interested)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest taking look at here for android: [Playing youtube video in Android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11550797/playing-youtube-video-in-android-app)

Just add the renderer with the right view for both platforms and afterwards you can use the API
PS: Who is Adam Fisher

EDIT: link for IOS: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/59329/playing-an-youtube-video-from-ios-app

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out.And I've been searching for a while about this issue, then I decided to post here for maybe a shot of luck. Adam Fisher is this dude https://gyazo.com/dfb06c158dbd56144857bf6ac4259330
He's in every thread, and I don't wanna pay for his solution, however simple it might be.

Comment: Okay haha, if this is the solution don't forget to mark it,  I also added an extra solution for ios in it so you know what view to use for it.