# How to play Youtube videos in Android Video View?

Tags: android, youtube, android-videoview

I am developing an android application which requires a youtube video player embedded within it. I successfully got the RTSP video URL from the API, but while trying to load this rtsp url in my android video view, it says "`Can't play this video.`". Previously I developed a similar application in this method, and it worked fine at that time, but it also failing to load now.

I'm sure about that, I'm getting the correct RTSP url from the API. `rtsp://v6.cache6.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAlV9VII3c64lRMYESARFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp`

Here is my activity code:

```
    mVideoURL = getIntent().getStringExtra("EXT_URL");
    Log.i("VIDEO URL", " " + mVideoURL);

    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    mVideoStreamView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vidPlayer);

    mVideoStreamView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(mVideoURL));
    mVideoStreamView.setMediaController(mc);
    mVideoStreamView.requestFocus();
    mVideoStreamView.start();
```

**EDIT**
Found some additional information from the logcat:

```
ARTSPConnection(6607): status: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
ASessionDescription(6607): v=0
ASessionDescription(6607): o=GoogleStreamer 378992432 328144046 IN IP4 74.125.213.182
ASessionDescription(6607): s=Video
ASessionDescription(6607): c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
ASessionDescription(6607): b=AS:29
ASessionDescription(6607): t=0 0
ASessionDescription(6607): a=control:*
ASessionDescription(6607): a=range:npt=0-1703.000000
ASessionDescription(6607): m=video 0 RTP/AVP 98
ASessionDescription(6607): b=AS:17
ASessionDescription(6607): a=rtpmap:98 H263-2000/90000
ASessionDescription(6607): a=control:trackID=0
ASessionDescription(6607): a=cliprect:0,0,144,176
ASessionDescription(6607): a=framesize:98 176-144
ASessionDescription(6607): a=fmtp:98 profile=0;level=10
ASessionDescription(6607): m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 99
ASessionDescription(6607): b=AS:12
ASessionDescription(6607): a=rtpmap:99 AMR/8000/1
ASessionDescription(6607): a=control:trackID=1
ASessionDescription(6607): a=fmtp:99 octet-align
ARTSPConnection(6607): status: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
ARTSPConnection(6607): status: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
ARTSPConnection(6607): status: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
ARTSPConnection(6607): status: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
ARTSPConnection(6607): status: RTSP/1.0 200 OK
ASessionDescription(6607): v=0
ASessionDescription(6607): o=GoogleStreamer 1299458498 503248054 IN IP4 74.125.213.182
ASessionDescription(6607): s=Video
ASessionDescription(6607): c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
ASessionDescription(6607): b=AS:29
ASessionDescription(6607): t=0 0
ASessionDescription(6607): a=control:*
ASessionDescription(6607): a=range:npt=0-1703.000000
ASessionDescription(6607): m=video 0 RTP/AVP 98
ASessionDescription(6607): b=AS:17
ASessionDescription(6607): a=rtpmap:98 H263-2000/90000
ASessionDescription(6607): a=control:trackID=0
ASessionDescription(6607): a=cliprect:0,0,144,176
ASessionDescription(6607): a=framesize:98 176-144
ASessionDescription(6607): a=fmtp:98 profile=0;level=10
ASessionDescription(6607): m=audio 0 RTP/AVP 99
ASessionDescription(6607): b=AS:12
ASessionDescription(6607): a=rtpmap:99 AMR/8000/1
ASessionDescription(6607): a=control:trackID=1
ASessionDescription(6607): a=fmtp:99 octet-align
ARTSPConnection(6607): status: RTSP/1.0 461 Unsupported Transport
ARTSPConnection(6607): status: RTSP/1.0 461 Unsupported Transport
```

Please suggest me a way to load youtube videos in android video view.

Thanks in Advance...

**EDIT**
Just checked in another device, HTC Desire (2.2). The code worked fine.
I'm wondering about thinking, What will be the problem with Nexus (4.1)??

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162088/video-view-not-playing-youtube-video

Comment: you should use youtube API for android, it very easiest way

Comment: Here is the link it will help .. http://www.truiton.com/2013/08/android-videoview-example-with-youtube-playback/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As I can't find any way to load the rtsp URL in video view (for all devices & android versions), I solved my problem with another work around. I used a webview to embed the youtube player within it, and this method working nicely in all tested devices.

Here is my code:

```
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + videoID + "?autoplay=1&vq=small");
mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

Thank you very much for all your help guys.

Comment: This should compulsary have flash player in device, but now the android(above 4.0) is no longer supporting flash content

Comment: Use this link .. http://www.truiton.com/2013/08/android-videoview-example-with-youtube-playback/

Answer (score 16):

```
private class YourAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(AlertDetail.this, "", "Loading Video wait...", true);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
        {
            try
            {
                String url = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1FJHYqE0RDg";
                videoUrl = getUrlVideoRTSP(url);
                Log.e("Video url for playing=========>>>>>", videoUrl);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Login Soap Calling in Exception", e.toString());
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
/*
            videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("rtsp://v4.cache1.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQk4RDShYkdS1BMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp"));
            videoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(AlertDetail.this));
            videoView.requestFocus();
            videoView.start();*/            
            videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(videoUrl));
            MediaController mc = new MediaController(AlertDetail.this);
            videoView.setMediaController(mc);
            videoView.requestFocus();
            videoView.start();          
            mc.show();
        }

    }

public static String getUrlVideoRTSP(String urlYoutube)
    {
        try
        {
            String gdy = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/";
            DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            String id = extractYoutubeId(urlYoutube);
            URL url = new URL(gdy + id);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            Document doc = documentBuilder.parse(connection.getInputStream());
            Element el = doc.getDocumentElement();
            NodeList list = el.getElementsByTagName("media:content");///media:content
            String cursor = urlYoutube;
            for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++)
            {
                Node node = list.item(i);
                if (node != null)
                {
                    NamedNodeMap nodeMap = node.getAttributes();
                    HashMap<String, String> maps = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    for (int j = 0; j < nodeMap.getLength(); j++)
                    {
                        Attr att = (Attr) nodeMap.item(j);
                        maps.put(att.getName(), att.getValue());
                    }
                    if (maps.containsKey("yt:format"))
                    {
                        String f = maps.get("yt:format");
                        if (maps.containsKey("url"))
                        {
                            cursor = maps.get("url");
                        }
                        if (f.equals("1"))
                            return cursor;
                    }
                }
            }
            return cursor;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("Get Url Video RTSP Exception======>>", ex.toString());
        }
        return urlYoutube;

    }

protected static String extractYoutubeId(String url) throws MalformedURLException
    {
        String id = null;
        try
        {
            String query = new URL(url).getQuery();
            if (query != null)
            {
                String[] param = query.split("&");
                for (String row : param)
                {
                    String[] param1 = row.split("=");
                    if (param1[0].equals("v"))
                    {
                        id = param1[1];
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (url.contains("embed"))
                {
                    id = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.e("Exception", ex.toString());
        }
        return id;
    }
```

Comment: I'm successfully getting the RTSP url from youtube API. My problem is that, I can't able to load that url in video view. I just find it out now that the issue is related with some rtsp protocol settings in my network.

Comment: I don't know what exactly the settings are. I edited my question already to include the log output that I'm getting while running the app.

Comment: is your app running perfectly as per your requirement

Comment: nope.. I'm getting the correct RTSP url from my code. But the video view is not loading the video.

Comment: ohh.. Now just checked the app with one another device, HTC Desire (2.2). And My Code working very well...!! Then, what will be problem with Nexus (4.1)...?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20919/discussion-between-midhu-and-nipun-gogia)

Comment: It does not work anymore, a message appears saying "Youtube is upgrading to a newer version”

Comment: while reteriveing file from rtsp it gives me exception --> FileNotFoundException: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/1FJHYqE0RDg ... I can't find this website also http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/  ... is there any other work around @NipunGogia

Answer (score 10):

Due to current version of YouTube you are likely to get a “Can’t play this video” error if you will use `VideoView` to show your video.

Take a look at this approcach with `YouTubePlayerView`:
http://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2014/03/17/android-development-play-youtube-video-in-your-app-cant-play-this-video-and-troubleshooting/

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35172585 there are old bugs, check if they're tackled before using it

Answer (score 4):

Use YouTube Android Player API. It works perfectly. Check my example from here:

activity_main.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context="com.example.andreaskonstantakos.vfy.MainActivity">

<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:visibility="visible"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:id="@+id/youtube_player"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<Button
android:text="Button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginBottom="195dp"
android:visibility="visible"
android:id="@+id/button" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.andreaskonstantakos.vfy;


import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeBaseActivity;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView;



public class MainActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity {

YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView;
Button button;
YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener onInitializedListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube_player);
     button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


     onInitializedListener = new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener(){

         @Override
         public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

            youTubePlayer.loadVideo("Hce74cEAAaE");

             youTubePlayer.play();
     }

         @Override
         public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

         }
     };

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

youTubePlayerView.initialize(PlayerConfig.API_KEY,onInitializedListener);
        }
    });
}
}
```

and the PlayerConfig.java class:

```
  package com.example.andreaskonstantakos.vfy;

/**
 * Created by Andreas Konstantakos on 13/4/2017.
 */

public class PlayerConfig {

PlayerConfig(){}

public static final String API_KEY = 
"xxxxx";
}
```

Replace the "Hce74cEAAaE" with your video ID from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hce74cEAAaE. Get your API_KEY from Console.developers.google.com and also replace it on the PlayerConfig.API_KEY. For any further information you can follow the following tutorial step by step: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3LiubyYpEUk

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15827116)

Comment: I guess it is usefull now.

Comment: issuetracker.google.com/issues/35172585 there are old bugs, check if they're tackled before using it

Answer (score 2):

Using Video View:

1.Code in the  layout xml:

```
<VideoView

       android:layout_width=”wrap_content”

       android:layout_height=”wrap_content”

       android:id=”@+id/YoutubeVideoView” />
```

2.Code in java class:

```
VideoView v = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.YoutubeVideoView);

v.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(“rtsp://v4.cache3.c.youtube.com/CjYLENy73wIaLQlW_ji2apr6AxMYDSANFEIJbXYtZ29vZ2xlSARSBXdhdGNoYOr_86Xm06e5UAw=/0/0/0/video.3gp”));

v.setMediaController(new MediaController(this)); //sets MediaController in the video view

// MediaController containing controls for a MediaPlayer                            

v.requestFocus();//give focus to a specific view

v.start();//starts the video
```

We set the VideoUri by specifying the 3gp link of Youtube video for mobile platforms. To add media controls such as Play, Pause, Rewind, Fast Forward and a progress slider ,we add MediaController to the VideoView.

uri.parse( 3gp link of the video  )...you can get this from youtube

Comment: I'm also using this same method, but the video is not loading. I think it may be rtsp protocol problem in my network. I edited my question to include some logs. Please have a look.. Thanks for your time..

Comment: i m posting another code which helps u to get RTSP url for video ..hope this will help you .....

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which Video codec format you are recieving your rtsp. There are certain devices which do not support running .mp4 file. Go through [Android Media support](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) for more information. Check if you can play any other .3gp files or not.

Comment: I'm receiving RTSP video URL from youtube API. They are .3gp files. Is there any way to load that video in `VideoView`, Android version 4.1. I'm getting correct output while trying the code with 2.2 version. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

After a long search, I found this way of implementation.

```
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.about_fragment, container, false);

    String frameVideo = "<html><body><br><iframe width=\"320\" height=\"200\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/XDYbEuY8nIc\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";

    WebView displayYoutubeVideo = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    displayYoutubeVideo.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    WebSettings webSettings = displayYoutubeVideo.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    displayYoutubeVideo.loadData(frameVideo, "text/html", "utf-8");
  return rootView;
    }
```

inside the layout.xml:

```
 <WebView android:id="@+id/videoView"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="-45dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"/>
```

This will work well.