# Youtube Video played in Android VideoView show "Youtube is upgrading to a newer version" video instead?

Tags: android, youtube, android-videoview

I have follow the [How to play Youtube videos in Android Video View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814055/how-to-play-youtube-videos-in-android-video-view?answertab=oldest#tab-top) and get VideoView to view YouTube video playing through the extracted RTSP.

However it doesn't play the original video, but play a message video as per the attached picture[image: YouTube Message]. Why is this happening? How could I access the original YouTube video to play?

Or is there another better way of playing with YouTube Video in the VideoView?

Thanks.

Comment: I would try https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/

Comment: Thanks jmhostalet. That's my workaround (or perhaps a better permanent solution). But it's still good to understand why this native approach is now having this issue.

Comment: Playing video in Android has been always a mess, a truly nightmare among devices and SDK versions, I think "YouTube Android Player API" is the way to solve all those problems.