# How to play Youtube video url in VrVideoView (Cardboard SDK) Android?

Tags: android, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I am trying to play youtube video using android cardboard sdk provided by google but I am not able to play it. 
Here is my code

```
Options options = new Options();
          options.inputFormat = Options.FORMAT_HLS;
          options.inputType = Options.TYPE_MONO; // for 360 video
          videoWidgetView.loadVideo(Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xyzzyz"), options);
```

**Error Log :**

E/VrVideoPlayer: 205251285AdaptiveMediaSourceEventListener.onLoadError com.google.a.a.g.v: Input does not start with the #EXTM3U header.

Comment: You can play youtube videos using VideoView check out this link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13814055/how-to-play-youtube-videos-in-android-video-view

Comment: Yes but I want to play video in VrVideoView (side by side video playing) not in VideoView.

Answer (score 0):

I got a example from github you can go through this link:https://github.com/googlevr/gvr-android-sdk

Comment: I am using the same sdk but i could not find code or method to play video from youtube url.

Comment: have you checked developer's site

Comment: @bhaumiksoni got any solution for this?