# How can i parse this video url from this api and play on my app ? is there any library in android like Picasso (for image)?

Tags: java, android, json, api, android-videoview

Here is the structure of the **API**. (JSON format).I have already parse title & subtitle from this API. But how can I parse this youtube video link and play it in android?

```
{
   "success": true, 
   "message": "All Contents of Nirdeshona Videos", 
    "data": [ 
        { 
            "id": 1, 
            "title": "New NVideo", 
            "sub_title": "New song",
            **"link": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lecITZkWqzg",**
            "status": 1,
            "created_at": "2019-10-01 08:41:29",
            "updated_at": "2019-10-01 08:41:29"<p>
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Use GSON for parsing. Its Handle your response.

Comment: You can parse link same like title because this both are in same object

Comment: i can parse but it wouldn't play.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43382280/8123836

Comment: checkout this to play video in videoview from url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399351/how-to-play-mp4-video-in-videoview-in-android

Comment: You can play it with Youtube Default player available here 

https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player

Answer (score 0):

You can use videoview class to display a video. Add this to your layout to display the video

```
<VideoView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/videoView" />
```

and then programmatically set your url and start the video.

```
VideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.videoView);
videoView.setVideoPath(myurl);
videoView.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for play youtube URL video in-app then below are the library for that with the various option in player.
https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/android-youtube-player