# Android VideoView not working

Tags: android, uri, media, android-videoview

I want to write the code which will play a video when a button is clicked. I can't get the video to display. When I click the button to play, the emulator stops working.

```
public class Video extends Activity{

private static final String MOVIE_URL = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XtYzTxydKmk&list=PL33CD04942E3B59AF&index=3";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.video_layout);

    VideoView video = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoHK);
    Uri HKvideo = Uri.parse(MOVIE_URL);
    video.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    video.setVideoURI(HKvideo);
    video.start();
    video.requestFocus();
}
```

For the button I have

```
Button videoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnVideo);
    videoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent video = new Intent(AboutHK.this, Video.class);
            startActivity(video);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private String MOVIE_URL = "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XtYzTxydKmk&list=...";
```

So at first when you want to play Video trough `VideoView` from youtube in phone, this String as `Uri` is not supported and it does not working. You need **RTSP Link**.

Here is [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5162088/video-view-not-playing-youtube-video) and there is guide [how to convert youtube links to RTSP](https://github.com/vrunoa/youtube-url2rtsp).

If you want to play video with classic `Uri` so you need to make it via `Intent`:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://www.youtube.com");
startActivity(i);
```

But i recommend to you read

- [YouTube Android Player
  API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/)
- [YouTube API
  v2.0](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol?hl=sk)